# How to set token expire time of UserCredential in C#?

Tags: c#, google-api

This is my code for creating credential.

```
            ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                ClientSecret = "XXXXXX"
            };

            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            secrets,
            new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

Now I want to set my token expire time is 120 seconds by this code

```
credential.Token.ExpiresInSeconds = 120;
```

But my setting time is later, the authentication is executed before. So my setting time is useless. So how can I set it first before execute the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

`ExpiresInSeconds` is a `UserCredential's Token's property`, you must set after a `UserCredential` created. And it'll have meaning only after `UserCredential` created.
`ExpiresInSeconds` mean this `UserCredential's Token` can be use for how long. When you got a token you don't need authorize anymore, when token expired you need reauthorize get another token. it's current Authorization valid time.